# Is there a way to handle associative arrays in machine learning without casting to a fixed index?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I have a (very large) data set that I'd like to set up a categorization algorithm for.

The data has the following form:

```
x: Associative array of data in the form [{key: String, r: Number}]
y: ID code (String) -> **Intended output code**
z: score from experimental testing (Number)
```

I'd really like to be able to pump all of this data into a model that allows me to input a new `x` with any set of `[{key, r}]` and return a `y` value that maximizes the `z` from experimental testing.

The issue I'm running into is that it's difficult to handle the format of `x` since it seems that most tech like tensorflow or Keras works best with direct matrix multiplication.

Short of creating an indexed array with a fixed position for each key, and fitting all of my data into that format, is there any way I can handle these sorts of associations indirectly?

Edit for Clarity: 
I have inputs of the form:

```
topics:[
[{
key: String, 
r: Number, 
subtopics:[{
    key: String, 
    r: Number, 
    subtopics:[{...}]
}]]
```

and I'd like each topic to only be compared against matching keys from the potential output classes.

I believe I'm correct in that it should be possible to generate an output class that can match partially in this way, but I just can't wrap my head around how to structure the math.

Thoughts and prayers also appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this article fairly explains it, but to summarize in case anyone else comes across this, it will first be necessary to use your training data to create a list of all topics and then use that to generate an n dimensional matrix which can serve as the library.

That matrix can then be used to encode each topic signature so that they can be parsed mathematically. In this example the matrix would be n dimensional, and if the r value for a particular topic was nonzero then that cell of the matrix would have that value.

TL;DR, no this isn't possible unless someone creates some kind of kickass library for parsing JSON with text and somehow inferring relationships. Maybe me :)

Source(ish): https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/869/neural-network-parse-string-data